# Change mod key in xmonad+gnome?

Tags: gnome, xmonad

I'm using gnome+xmonad, and I'm trying to set the mod key to the windows key. I set my .xmonad.hs file to:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome

main = xmonad gnomeConfig
myModMask = mod4Mask
```

I tried to reload the file with alt+q, but no change seems to have occurred. Any suggestions? I'm far from a power user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but not quite. It should be:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome

main = xmonad gnomeConfig
    { modMask = mod4Mask }
```